# Notation for "stacking" tuples

Tags: notation, vectors

Is there a formal mathematical notation for stacking/concatenating two or more tuples? i.e. if $a=(7, 2, 4)$, $b = (2, 2, 0)$ and $c = (8, 5)$, the resulting "stacked" tuple would be $(7, 2, 4, 2, 2, 0, 8, 5)$.

[EDIT]: would this notation be the same as stacking a tuple and a single item? i.e. if $d = 8$ then stacking $a$ and $d$ gives $(7, 2, 4, 8)$, and $d$ then $a$ gives $(8, 7, 2, 4)$

Comment: You could write it as $(a,b,c)$. From a set theoric point of view it's not correct, but it's a widely known abuse of notation (and an $n$-tuple can be defined similarly, using recursion).

Comment: The closest I know is the [direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum), denoted with $\oplus$. So I suggest $a \oplus b \oplus c.$

Comment: For adding a single item I would suggest $a \oplus (d) = (7,2,4,8),$ but you can of course abuse notation and just write $a \oplus d.$ But make it clear what you mean with the notation and that you will just write $a \oplus d$ instead of $a \oplus (d).$